# Copy and Rename Folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with numerous linked workbooks. I would like to store a master copy of it within the C:\ drive. When someone needs to use it they would click on the below macro to copy the folder, ask what the new name will be and place it on the desktop for use. The below code cycles through but does not place the folder on the desktop. It just seems to disappear and does not copy the original

Hoping someone can help??

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim strName As String


FromPath = "C:\v4 Master Operations Folder"  
ToPath = "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop"
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Reenter:
strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter the name of your operation", _
Title:="Operation.", Default:=" ")

If strName = vbNullString Then
MsgBox "Incorrect Entry."
GoTo Reenter

End If

If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
    FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
End If

If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
    ToPath = Left(ToPath & strName, Len(ToPath) - 1)
End If

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath & strName
MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath & strName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem is on this line:

```
FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath & strName
```

You are setting your `Destination` variable equal to `ToPath & strName`, so if the user enters "My name" then it would be "C:\Users\Owner\DesktopMy Name".  You need to put a slash in there: `Destination:=ToPath & "\" & strName`